# extjs cellediting event passing activecolumn as null

Tags: javascript, extjs, plugins, extjs6.2

This happens with extjs versions 6.2+. I have a cellediting plugin which has a listener event on edit. When the onEdit is called, I am trying to check the xtype of the edited cell and it fails since active columns are passed as nulls. This works fine with earlier versions. As per research, this could be a bug which never got fixed in extjs versions and don't see any workaround yet. If anybody come across this, please advise.

**Problem**: On cellediting, editor.activecolumn is null. It works fine with earlier versions. Looks like ExtJs 6.2 CellEditing plugin editor.el.dom always passes null.

Panel Layout :

```
    hideHeaders: false,
sortableColumns: false,
rowLines: true,
collapsible: false,
titleCollapse: true,
layout: 'auto',
title: 'Test Page',
selModel: 'cellmodel',
plugins: {
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    listeners: {
        beforeedit: 'isEditable',
        edit: 'onEdit'
    }
}
```

Above code will trigger onEdit and below is the function:

```
    onEdit: function(editor, c, e) {

    // combobox check
    if (editor.activeColumn.config.editor.xtype === 'combo') {
                 console.log("it's combo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, starting from ExtJS 6.2 the `activeColumn` property is no more available from the editor object on `edit`. But you shouldn't have relied on it in the first place, as it's not documented, and there are other means to achieve what you want.

Take a look at the [context](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/CellEditing.js.html#Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-edit) (second argument) that is passed to the `edit` event listener. Among other things, it has a `column` property, which is what you need. So in your case, you can replace

```
onEdit: function(editor, c, e) {
    if (editor.activeColumn.config.editor.xtype === 'combo') {
         console.log("it's combo");
    }
}
```

with

```
onEdit: function(editor, context) {
    if (context.column.config.editor.xtype === 'combo') {
         console.log("it's combo");
    }
}
```

and it will work across all version of ExtJS 6.